# Anycast network - steps required to implement one?

Tags: domain-name-system, anycast

As part of our cloud-based security service, we have a DNS server deployed in the cloud. Instead of providing different IPs to customers in different geo-locations, we want to use a unified Anycast network that can provide the myriad benefits of Anycast DNS (single DNS IP, DoS protection, lower latency etc).

While it is clear to us how Anycast DNS works at a high level, it is not clear how we can go about building a network like this on our own. We are an Amazon AWS shop at the moment, but can consider alternatives. It appears to us that we need to set up datacenters and talk to carriers for this?

Can anyone point us to a list of steps or who we should talk to get one setup?

Vinay.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find running an anycast network on AWS to be a challenge.

Rather, to succeed in building your own anycast system you'll first need to master BGP, and yes, as you guessed, probably setting up your own data centers.  From there, you'll need to create a system that is effectively stateless.

Once you have those figured out, feel free to come back with more substantive questions.

Comment: What other alternatives are there?